# Is the topological square root well defined up to homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

This question arose from [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60375/is-mathbb-r3-the-square-of-some-topological-space) stack overflow post. For a topological space $Y$, if there exists a topological space $X$ such that $X \times X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$ then $X$ is called a "topological square root" of $Y$. I was wondering now whether this topological square root is well defined up to homeomorphism, that is to say:
\begin{equation}
 A \times A \cong B  \times B \implies A \cong B 
\end{equation}

I am aware that the implication holds the other way, since if $f: A \to B$ is a homeomorphism then so is $f \times f : A \times A \to B \times B$, however I've not been able to prove whether the implication in the equation above is true and am now starting to suspect that there is indeed a counterexample.

I'm aware of products not being "cancellable", that is to say, if $M \times X \cong N \times X$ then it is not necessarily true that $M \cong N$, with a counterexample being $X = \mathbb{R}$, $N = \mathbb{R}^3$ and $M$ being the [Dogbone Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogbone_space). This suggests that perhaps there is a counterexample to the question posed, though I'm not sure since in this case there's only 2 spaces.

Comment: This sounds way too good to be true.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma likely can anwer, or at least provide a good ref.

Comment: @MSIS:  I just wanted to let you know the sad news that Henno passed away in March of this year.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Thanks for telling me. Really sorry to hear it.